# Assign HTML file to Message.Body in c#

Tags: c#, html, html-email

I want to assign a full HTML file to the email body, I want to assign this file to message body, I put:

> message.IsBodyHtml = true;

I can used this to assign the, line by line

```
"Welcome to our system",
"<b>Thanks to join to our system !<br /><br />",
```

But Is there a way to assign afull HTML file to the body ? I have a HTML file that contain design for email body.

Hope that clear.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: AppPath not exist in Silverlight ?

Comment: `AppPath ` is the name of a variable for storing `Request.PhysicalApplicationPath`.

Comment: " Request does not exist in the current context", I work on Silverlight application !! I can not know how to give the path for the text file :(

Comment: I think in Silverlight it should be something like this:`string AppPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"EmailTemplates\", EmailTemplate.txt);`

Comment: " File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied." That drives me crazy

Comment: Try this:`Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"EmailTemplates\EmailTemplate.txt")`

Answer (score 1):

You should create an `EmailTemplate`.

- Add new Folder to your project for example `EmailTemplates`
- Add new text file to `EmailTemplates` folder for example `EmailTemplate.txt`
- Write your HTML template in `EmailTemplate.txt`
- Then in the code:

  ```
  string AppPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(AppPath + "EmailTemplates/EmailTemplate.txt");
  message.IsBodyHtml = true;
  message.Body = sr.ReadToEnd();
  sr.Close();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the file to your project resources:

Project Properties > Resources > Add Existing File

In code use: Resources.ResourceName

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way is use T4 templates.

**You create T4 template file**

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ parameter name="Email" type="System.String" #>
<p>Here is text for <#= Email #></p>
```

Then you can **process template before sending mail**:

```
MyTemplate template = new MyTemplate 
{
   Session = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
      { "Email", "some@email.com" }
   }
};

template.Initialize();
string body = template.TransformText();
```

And finally **send email with your html body**:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(this.emailConfiguration.SmtpUser, email)
{
   IsBodyHtml = true,
   Body = body,
   Subject = "Your email subject"
};
```

I prefer this solution for both (html body / text body) cases, because:

- template is clean and as the part of solution
- you can add custom variables into template

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to ask how can I get the path for the template file in Silverlight application?

Comment: If you add T4 template file, VS automatically generates .cs file corresponding to your template. It means, if you create MyTemplate.tt file, you can instantiate it as MyTemplate.cs (`new MyTemplate {...}`)

Comment: How can I add T4 Template in silverlight ?

Comment: T4 in Silverlight: http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-use-t4-templates-in-wp7-silverlight-desktop-or-even-monodroid-apps/